# Color of leaf change

Tags: leaves

I have clematis and other plants that the leaves start out a dark green and then, as it continues to grow, new leaves loose the color and are light yellow. And, the same thing happens in reverse; starts light and eventually turn green. I’ve put on iron, miracle grow and other fertilizers. Nothing changes.

Comment: Are the plants in containers or in the ground? Can you add a couple of photos? And are you saying a plant  starts out green,turns yellow, then turns green again?